# update object from reducer to useState

Tags: react-native, redux, react-hooks, reduce, redux-toolkit

I will try to update an object in reducer, once state is updated in reducer then i set the value using useState in functional component. But first time its working when i try to updated second time its not updated, showing only previous value. ReactNative

```
**Component**
const Catpoint = () => {
const { cPoint} = useSelector((state) => state.ckpoint)
const [ckpt, setCKPT] = useState(cPoint)

useEffect(()=>{
  setCKPT(cPoint)
},[cPoint])

const updatecPoint =  () => {
  ckpt.options =[{user:"suresh", status:"0"}, {user:"alex", status:"1" ]
  dispatch(updateCKPT(ckpt)
}
}

return <View>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> updatecPoint() }> Update User Status </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
export default Catpoint

**Reducer**

const initialcpoinState = {
cPoint:{
  pointName:"test",
  options:[{user:"suresh", status:"0"}, {user:"alex", status:"0" ]
}
}

const cpointSlice = createSlice({
    name: "cpointData",
    initialState: initialcpoinState,
    reducers: {
     updateCheckpointInfo:(state, action) => {
         
           Object.assign(state.cPoint, {...action.payload})

     }
})

export const {
    updateCheckpointInfo
} = cpointSlice.actions

export default cpointSlice
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic case of [mutating state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/updating-objects-in-state#whats-a-mutation).  The mutation occurs in this line:

```
ckpt.options = [{user:"suresh", status:"0"}, {user:"alex", status:"1"}]
```

You cannot mutate the `ckpt` object because it is a React state.  In this case you're actually messing up your Redux state too.  The initial value of the `ckpt` state comes from your `useSelector` hook so it is the same object instance in both places.  Mutating one will change the other.

---

There is no need to have a local component state at all.  Just `dispatch` the changes which you want to apply to the checkpoint and the `cPoint` variable from the `useSelector` hook will update automatically.

Your reducer is already merging the `action.payload` with the existing `state.cPoint` so you do not need to pass a complete checkpoint object in your action.  You can simply pass the fields which you want to change.

```
const Catpoint = () => {
  const { cPoint } = useSelector((state) => state.ckpoint);

  const updatecPoint = () => {
    dispatch(
      updateCKPT({
        options: [{ user: "suresh", status: "0" }, { user: "alex", status: "1" }]
      })
    );
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => updatecPoint()}>
        Update User Status
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

export default Catpoint;
```